# Undefined symbol errors with libHSghc-prim when compiling FFI sample

Tags: haskell, gcc, compilation, linker, ghc

I'm trying to compile the sample code in the [FFI chapter of the GHC User's Guide](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.4.1/docs/html/users_guide/shared_libs.html), which I can compile fine using another computer:

**Foo.hs**

```
module Foo where

foreign export ccall foo :: Int -> IO Int

foo :: Int -> IO Int
foo n = return (length (f n))

f :: Int -> [Int]
f 0 = []
f n = n:(f (n-1))
```

**Foo.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "HsFFI.h"

#ifdef __GLASGOW_HASKELL__
#include "Foo_stub.h"
#endif

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int i;

  hs_init(&argc, &argv);

  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    printf("%d\n", foo(2500));
  }

  hs_exit();
  return 0;
}
```

**Compilation and execution**

```
ghc --make -dynamic -shared -fPIC Foo.hs -o libfoo.so
ghc -no-hs-main Foo.c libfoo.so
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./a.out
```

But when running `a.out` I get the error "./a.out: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/ghc-8.4.3/ghc-prim-0.5.2.0/libHSghc-prim-0.5.2.0-ghc8.4.3.so: undefined symbol: stg_traceMarkerzh"
When compiling other simple FFI code I get errors about other undefined symbols in libHSghc-prim.

If I run `objdump -t libHSghc-prim-0.5.2.0-ghc8.4.3.so`, I see that there are no symbols in the symbol table. After receiving the error I updated GHC from 8.4.2 to 8.4.3 in the Arch Linux repositories, which updated libHSghc-prim from version 0.5.0.0 to 0.5.2.0, so I would have assumed these newly installed files are in order. How can I troubleshoot this problem?

**ldd libHSghc-prim-0.5.2.0-ghc8.4.3.so**

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc9e7a4000)
/lib/$LIB/liblsp.so => /lib/lib/liblsp.so (0x00007ff31abdf000)
libm.so.6 => /usr/lib/libm.so.6 (0x00007ff31a84a000)
libc.so.6 => /usr/lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007ff31a48e000)
libdl.so.2 => /usr/lib/libdl.so.2 (0x00007ff31a28a000)
/usr/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007ff31b272000)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. As the ghc version in the Arch Linux repositories uses dynamic linking, which makes executable sizes much smaller and is also [documented](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Haskell), I have to compile my programs with dynamic linking, so I just had to add a flag:

```
ghc -dynamic -no-hs-main Foo.c libfoo.so
```